# How to get the value of 2 columns from the same row using aggregate functions?

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have the next table:

Table SALES

| Id | CustomerId | Date | NumItems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-01-14 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 | 2023-01-16 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 2023-01-10 | 9 |

I'm grouping the rows by CustomerId and I need to get the one whose date is the most recent:

```
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    MAX(Date),
    NumItems  <--- (?)
FROM SALES 
GROUP BY CustomerId
```

But I also need to get number of items from the same row. How can I complement my query to get that column?

If the most recent registry is the second one (2023-01-16), I have to get the number of items from that row as well, which would be 6.

Comment: This can be done using the ROW_NUMBER() Windowing function.
See the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group).

Comment: Please don't tag conflicting products, just tag the one you're actually using.

Comment: Now we went from two DBMS tags (sql-server and postgresql)  to none. One or the other would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows :

```
with cte as (
  SELECT
    CustomerId,
    MAX(Date) as Date
  FROM SALES 
  GROUP BY CustomerId
)
select c.*, s.NumItems
from cte c
inner join SALES s on s.CustomerId = c.CustomerId and c.Date = s.Date
```

a subquery to get the recent date and then using `inner join` to get `NumItems`